# Angular serialize Date with specific format in POST request

Tags: json, angular, date, json-serialization, angular7

I am new to Angular and I have several doubts about what is the best way to serialize a Date property of an object added to a POST request.
Given the sample class

```
export class MyClass{
    public dateProperty: Date;
}
```

I have the following code in the service:

```
public addMyClass(myClass: MyClass): Observable<MyClass> {
    return this.http.post<MyClass>(this.apiBaseUrl, myClass);
}
```

I have to serialize Date in the following format `'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'`.
I considered different ways like defining a decorator (if possible), or overriding `toJson()` method, but I don't know if these are the only options or there is a better solution...

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I used [formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate) to format properly the Date before to send it.

Answer (score 8):

Describing the problem that I had, I was at GMT+1, for instance, and would like to save just the date, something like "2019-04-28T00:00:00 GMT+01:00", and the JSON serialization was changing the date to "2019-04-27T23:00:00.000Z".  Basically sending the wrong date, I guess you are facing something similar.

I found a wait to custom serialize everything at once for the whole project before sending it to the server, and it was by overwriting the toJSON function at the data object:

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return moment(this, moment.ISO_8601 ).format();
};
```

I'm also using moment.js.  Hope it helps.